# Naming convention for a voltage follower op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, schematics

I have a voltage divider which creates a 1V signal that is sent to a voltage follower op amp.

[image]

This might be a silly question, but is there a well accepted naming convention for this very common type of circuit? "+1V raw" and "+1V" sounds a bit weird but I didn't know what to name these ports.

Since this is a very, very common circuit, I thought there should be some sort of unwritten convention on these?

Thanks

Comment: \$ V_{REF} \$ (reference) is common. \$ +1V_{REF} \$ is an option but may look like part of an equation and cause some confusion.

Comment: also not that it would be a *very* good idea to stabilize your "raw" voltage using an appropriately sized capacitor. Otherwise, your reference voltage will contain all the fluctuation of the +5V rail, and that is usually a *really bad idea™*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a well accepted naming convention for this

No.

Make up whatever you want.

If the output of the voltage divider only goes to the opamp, then one way to deal with this is to put both on the same page and connect them directly.  That alleviates the need to name the "raw" net at all.

If I was forced to name both nets, I might pick something like V1RAW and V1BUF, but really, that's up to my whim at the time.  As long as the names at least remind you of the function and aren't terribly verbose, they'll do.

Answer (score 2):

The opamp is functioning as a "buffer" so you could call its output "+1V_buffered". But that seems rather verbose, so "+1V_raw" (which is not widely distributed) and "+1V" (which is) seem to be entirely appropriate labels in this situation.

Just as an aside, and assuming you want to stay with the E12 series of resistors, making R1 = 33kΩ and R2 = 8.2kΩ gives you a better approximation to a nominal 1.00V from your divider — 0.61% error vs. 2.08% error.

Comment: Good point. I don't have these values in 1206 though (my go to SMD resistor). I guess I'll keep +V1_raw then!